# Symfony4 Define Environnement variables in production

Tags: php, apache, symfony4

In a production context the environment variables must be configured at the apache level. I tried through a .htaccess file and a SetEnv directive. Without success. The $ _ENV variable does not contain my variable.

For information, I have a shared hosting at OVH. I'm not sure they allow setting variables by SetEnv.

How I can define environment variables via apache and not directly setting the variable $ _ENV ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to read this **ISSUE:**

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/19015

Comment: Thank you. This leads me more and more towards a limitation of shared hosting from my host.